# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'module') in Node 18

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, webpack

Trying to upgrade node version 14x to 18x. Got many node module dependency error & that was taken care of. However, for this one tried so many ways available on the web but not resolved.

[image]

[image]

Manually installed node 18 on my local. Updated react-script 4 to 5. Installed util and added as fallback in craco.config file. Installed node-polyfill-webpack-plugin and added as plugin in craco.config file.

Why am I getting this above issue?

Comment: I think your problem is with the craco upgrade and not with node.